# Integrating with Umbraco using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, umbraco

I'm using Umbraco CMS in my projects, currently server-side language is .NET C#.
As a part of code modernization, we want to move from .NET into NodeJS, but we still need to use Umbraco CMS.
Is there an existing comfortable way of integrating with Umbraco using NodeJS? - The whole existing C# functionality, using Node.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

No you would have to use .Net server side. Of course you can always create rest apis to access all of the CMS content via whatever technology you choose.

Saying that, Umbraco 9 should be released this year which will be moving to .Net Core.  This, I think, will make the Umbraco proposition right on trend again :) since we will not be tied to Windows any more.